# Save a continues netstat to a text file with time stamp

Tags: netstat

I want to make a continuous netstat to a specific port to show the establishment with date and time.
the command I am using is the below:
netstat -na | find "5002", but it shows the current status only
I tried also
netstat -na | find "5002" > c:\netstat.txt but it printout the current status only as well.

appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), set it to only filter network activity (toolbar buttons), and disable "Options > Show resolved network addresses".

Add the filter for `Path` `contains` `5002` (although `Path` `ends with` `:5002` might be closer to what you're actually describing).

When done, use "Save" to export the capture log as CSV.